# Facebook messenger android People menu red circle with 1

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger

I am using Facebook messenger on Android.  On the initial screen when I open Messenger there are the "Chats" and "People" menus.  The "People" menu has a red circle with a 1 inside it.  Also at the top right hand side of the screen there is the icon that has a + sign and a person icon.  This also has a red circle with a 1 in it.  When I click this icon, the "Add Contacts" screen opens.
On this screen there are two lists of people.  There is the regular list of "Suggested People".  Above this list is a new list of "Updates".  This "Updates" list shows one person that I recently interacted with, but am not Facebook friends with.
I don't see any obvious action that Facebook Messenger is prompting me to take with regard to this one person to make the "red circle with the 1 in it" go away.  Is it saying that it's requirng me to become Facebook friends with this person, in order to make the "red circle with a 1 in it" go away?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be an actual programming question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, didn't foun a solution, but I uninstalled and installed the app again - it helped :)

Comment: Sorry, after a day it came back, still didn't found a solution.